# How do I make my program Print the H variable after Hello

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title("Matchstick Game")
root.iconbitmap("match.ico")
root.geometry("1000x580")

H = Entry(root, width = 80, fg = 'red').pack()
def clickme():
mylabel = Label(root, text = "Hello" + H.get()).pack()

my_button = Button(root, text = "whats your name", 
padx=10,pady=10,bg='white',fg='green',command=clickme).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

Jason Harper in the comments has the right answer. Separating the `.pack()` statements from the Label and Entry definitions will fix the error.

Here is what I got

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Matchstick Game")
#root.iconbitmap("match.ico")
root.geometry("1000x580")

H = tk.Entry(master = root, width = 80, fg = 'red')
H.pack()

def clickme():
    mylabel = tk.Label(root, text = ( "Hello" + H.get()))
    mylabel.pack()

my_button = tk.Button(root, text = "whats your name", 
padx=10,pady=10,bg='white',fg='green',command=clickme)

my_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

`pack()` function of `Entry` returns None, so you're storing `None` in H.
What you want to do is store the Entry object in H, and then call pack method on it later.

```
H = Entry(root, width = 80, fg = 'red')
H.pack()
```